# Special characters issue in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, special-characters

I am working on a project where a user enters his info and I save it into database, a user posted a string in the form "**I still am…**". But the string stored in database as "**I still amâ€¦**".

Now I am wondering why this happened, by looking at the string it is cleared that the suffix used after **am** is a kind of special characters and is converted into `â€¦`.

Comment: The search term you re looking for is "character encoding". This can go wrong in multiple ways in several places along the line.

Comment: @Hulk then what's the way to sort out this issue?

Comment: Does the String arrive correctly in php?

Comment: @Hulk yes it is arrived in the same form as i posted

Comment: Look up which encoding your DB is using, you may have to convert to it explicitly: [php manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

Comment: @Hulk i am using "utf8_unicode_ci" for the field in which the value stores

Comment: Ok - now what happens when you convert your String from your server encoding to that encoding before storing it?

Comment: it coverts it into â€¦

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the UTF-8 as the connection to a database too. It is set to Windows 1252 by default. (This encoding is often incorrectly labelled ISO 8859-1.)

The bytes `E2 80 A6` are rendered as `…` in UTF-8 and as `â€¦` in Windows 1252. The PHP is most of the time unaware of an encoding and pass raw bytes.